# PHP: (PDO) Mysql most effective way to add sting to returned value out of db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a mysql database I store some image names without the exact path.
So what I like to do is add the path before I load the returned array into jQuery (json) to use it in the JQ Galleria plugin.

In the columns I've got names likes this:

```
  11101x1xTN.png 11101x2xTN.png 11101x3xTN.png
```

Which in the end should be like:

```
  ./test/img/cars/bmw/11101/11101x1xTN.png
  ./test/img/cars/bmw/11101/11101x2xTN.png
```

I could just add the whole path into the database but that seems 1. a wast of db space. 2. Then I need to update he whole db if the images path changes. 
I could edit the jQuery plugin but it doesn't seem practical to update the source code of it.

What is the right thing to do and the fasted for processing?
Can you add a string after you make a db query and before you fetch the results?

part of the function where I make the query:

```
    $needs = "thumb, image, big, title, description";
    $result = $get_queries->getImagesById($id, $needs);


    $sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT $needs FROM images WHERE id = :stockId");     
    $sth->bindParam(":stockId", $id);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

this is the foreach loop:

```
$addurl = array('thumb', 'image', 'big');

foreach ($result as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $item => $val) {
        if (in_array($item, $addurl)){

            $val = '/test/img/cars/bmw/11101/'.$val;                
        }

    }
}
```

the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [thumb] => 11101x1xTN.png
        [image] => 11101x1xI.png
        [big] => 11101x1xB.png
        [title] => Title
        [description] => This a blub.
    )
 )
```

The url should be add to thumb, image and big.
I tried to change the array values using a foreach loop but that didn't work. Also not noting if the use of that would course a unnecessary slowdown.

Comment: `I tried to change the array values using a foreach loop but that didn't work.` - **This** should have been your question, not all these useless details about PDO. Show your loop and your silly problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you almost nailed it. only thing you forgot is to store your $val back in array.

```
foreach ($result as $i => $array) {    
    foreach ($array as $item => $val) {    
        if (in_array($item, $addurl)){    
            $val = '/test/img/cars/bmw/11101/'.$val;
            $result[$i][$item] = $val;
        }    
    }    
}
```

however, I'd make it little shorter

```
foreach ($result as $i => $array) { 
    foreach ($addurl as $item) { 
            $result[$i][$item] = '/test/img/cars/bmw/11101/'.$array[$item];
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array looks like this:

```
$result = array("11101x1xTN.png", "11101x2xTN.png", "11101x3xTN.png");
```

A simple [`array_map()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used.

```
$result_parsed = array_map(function($str) { return './test/img/cars/bmw/11101/'.$str; }, $result);
```

As seen **[Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ubUaIi)**